# How to create and access an array of objects for a SMITE minigame i am writing

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I am creating a program that needs to have an array of 100 strings. Each string refers to a mythological god in the game SMITE. This god has 3 important attributes that determine what items the god is allowed to use.

**1: ability Class: warrior, mage, guardian, hunter, assassin.**

**2: Range: Melee or Range.**

**3: Damage type: Magical or Physical**

Basically this program gets a random god, and builds 6 random items from the allowed list it can access based on these attributes.

These attributes will be looked at in order to determine what items the god is allowed to use. there will be around 150 items, and these items are only able to be used by a specific class, range, and damage type.

I have a current solution that works but unfortunately i have to create an entire string array with all of the gods that belong to each type. For example i create an array with 50 magical gods, then an array with 20 mages. 
in order to determine which items that god can use i am checking the randomly generated god String against all of the arrays that determine its type, and if it is found then flag that type. I am wondering if it is possible to store these gods as objects with all of these identifiers. Example. The god "Anubis" would have the mage ability class, the ranged range type, and the magical damage type, all stored in the one object that defines Anubis. That way i would not have to create tons of long Arrays full of god names and check them against each other. If this is possible please someone help. I am currently in a programming class for C++ and we have not covered OOP but i am somewhat familiar with it because of python.

```
const int NUM_GODS = 100;
string god_list[NUM_GODS] = {"Achilles", "Agni", "Ah Muzen Cab", "Ah Puch", "Amaterasu",\
"Anhur", "Anubis", "Ao Kuang", "Aphrodite", "Apollo", "Arachne", "Ares", "Artemis",\
"Artio", "Athena", "Awilix", "Bacchus", "Bakasura", "Baron Samedi",\
"Bastet", "Bellona", "Cabraken", "Camazotz", "Cerberus", "Cernunnos",\
"Chaac", "Chang'e", "Chernobog", "Chiron", "Chronos", "Cu Chulainn",\
"Cupid", "Da Ji", "Discordia", "Erlang Shen"}; //There are many many more but this is just a sample for an idea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current goals in mind I would structure your code something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream> // needed for stringstream
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>

enum class AbilityType {
    WARRIOR,
    MAGE,
    GUARDIAN,
    HUNTER,
    ASSASSIN,
    HEALER
};

enum class AttackType {
    MELEE,
    RANGE
};

enum class DamageType {
    MAGICAL,
    PHYSICAL
};

struct EntityAttributes {
    AbilityType abilityType;
    AttackType attackType;
    DamageType damageType;
};

class Entity {
private:
    std::string name_;
    EntityAttributes attribs_;

public:
    Entity() = default;
    explicit Entity(const std::string& name) : 
        name_(name) 
    {}
    Entity(const std::string& name, EntityAttributes attribs) :
        name_(name),
        attribs_(attribs)
    {}

    void assignAttributes(EntityAttributes attribs) {
        attribs_ = attribs;
    }

    std::string getName() const { return name_; }

    AbilityType getAbilityType() const { return attribs_.abilityType; }
    AttackType getAttackType() const { return attribs_.attackType; }
    DamageType getDamageType() const { return attribs_.damageType; }
};

void getAllLinesFromFile(const char* filename, std::vector<std::string>& output) {
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "failed to open file " << filename << '\n';
        throw std::runtime_error(stream.str());
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        if (line.size() > 0)
            output.push_back(line);
    }
    file.close();
}

int main() {
    try {
        // This will store all of the names in from our text file.
        std::vector<std::string> names;
        getAllLinesFromFile("Names.txt", names);

        // This will give us a container of all of our entities with a provided name
        // after this container is filled you can go back later and add the addition
        // properties, or if you read the properties in from a file as well you can use
        // the other Entity constructor to generate all of them with their names and properties
        std::vector<Entity> entities;
        for (auto& n : names) {
            Entity e(n);
            entities.push_back(e);
        }

        // Check our array of Entities
        std::cout << "There are " << entities.size() << " entities\n";
        for (auto& e : entities) {
            std::cout << e.getName() << '\n';
        }

    } catch( std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

---

In the example above the basic text file "Names.txt" has the name of the entity on a single line. I read the file by extracting line by line because if we only did a single `cin >> string` it would only get the first set of characters until it encountered a white space. So the text file for the entities names look like this:

*-Names.txt-*

```
Achilles
Agni
Ah Muzen Cab
Ah Puch
Amaterasu
Anhur
Anubis
Ao Kuang
Aphrodite
Apollo
Arachne
Ares
Artemis
Artio
Athena
Awilix
Bacchus
Bakasura
Baron Samedi
Bastet
Bellona
Cabraken
Camazotz
Cerberus
Cernunnos
Chaac
Chang'e
Chernobog
Chiron
Chronos
Cu Chulainn
Cupid
Da Ji
Discordia
Erlang Shen
```

This is fairly straight forward and simple to do. Now if you wanted to add to this text file the different attributes that each of these entities are capable of using you can surely do that, however it will make parsing the file a little harder. If this was the case then characters with names that have more than one word would have to be enclosed with some kind of special character such as the quotes `" "`. I'll give a simple example of what a text file might look like; however the method to read in the text might be similar but the method of parsing the strings within the stored vector will be different.

```
Achilles Warrior Melee Physical   // easy enough only single words to extract from the vector
"Baron Samedi" Mage Range Magical // Here when we parse this line, Baron Samedi is in quotes so that would be our "name" variable then the rest would follow as before.
```

---

The enumerated types here are scoped enumerators because of the `class` declaration this way you can not interchange values like this:

```
AttackType attType = PHYSICAL; // This will fail to compile.
AttackType attType = DamageType::PHYSICAL; // will still fail to compile.
```

as they will generate the necessary compiler errors for you.

Also by using vectors above to store your class type, you do not have to explicitly have a specified number of entities and this value does not have to be known at compile time. With this code struture you do not have to use raw arrays and you don't have to worry about going out of bounds with indexing into an array. Here `std::vector` does all of that for you!

---

This is just something to think about in your overall design structure. This makes resource management easy, the code is easier to read and debug. It is reusable and should be fairly portable. You can always modify a text file to make changes to your list of characters and their attributes without having to rebuild or recompile your code, all you have to do is modify your text file and run the program again. This also helps to decrease compile and build times.

Comment: Why am i getting "incomplete type is not allowed" for the 3 references to stream? std::stringstream stream also at stream << ... and stream.srt()

Comment: Oh; in my function to read in a line of text from file I am using `stringstream` so up in the include section next to string also include `<sstream>` I had forgotten about that because I already have it in a long list of includes. I'll fix the code above but nice catch.

Comment: One thing i am wondering after looking deeper, why is name being passed by reference to Entity if we aren't changing the value in anyway to be reflected in the address?

Comment: It is not being passed by reference. It is being passed as a const reference. There is a difference between the two. This should prevent std::string's `copy constructor` from being called making unnecessary copies. This way it is using a reference to populate the container of entities. This should save on cpu write cycles.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. You rock! Thank you so much.